# Is CSS (and derivates SASS, SCSS, ...) is it safe to allow user upload? Is there a security issue?

Tags: css, security

pre: I was here [SO: Coldfusion: What are security issues that can occur if I allow users to upload .css and .js files to my site](http://Is%20CSS%20(and%20derivates%20SASS,%20SCSS,%20...)%20save%20to%20allow%20user%20upload?%20Is%20there), but it talks about `js`, in the first

I talk/ask about `CSS,SASS,SCSS` only, is the a security problem, if I allow users to upload (template - like) `CSS`

- for themselves
- for others, if they make the template public (not talking abut ugly, or porn background - thats an other story)

and if, what do I have to check?

or just - better not?

(side note, *trusted* users, will be allowed to contribute even more complex templates, with .rb, .js , .haml, but these will step through clearing and demployment steps ..., for `CSS` alone I am not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a lot of the security around file uploads are implementation specific (f.ex could I find a way to trick your CSS validation into acception a php file?). There are a few concerns assuming your implementation is solid:

1) CSS files can execute JavaScript (persistent xss) which could be used to upload a malicious file of a trusted user where to view a page contacting the malicious CSS.

2) CSS files can completely rewrite the way a website displays and could be used to replace legitimate content with offensive images for example.

Serving user supplied content can be made safer by serving it from a separate (sub)domain and setting appropriate security headers for your website.

Answer (score 0):

based on @wireghouls answer

> CSS files can execute JavaScript (persistent xss)

I found a use full link for others probably looking at my question, that shows: "it is not the best idea to let user upload css w/o white listed control."

... and learned, that there is a better place to ask my question:

[stackexchange/security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/css-based-attacks)

that explains the close quesstion request in my question